# jQuery: find a div containing part of the URL and add ID to div

Tags: jquery, find, attr, indexof, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of div's in my code which have a custom data-attribute assigned to them which is "data-for".

What I need to do is find the div which has a data-for attribute that matches part of the URL.

For example, the list of div's may be:

```
<div data-for="north-west"></div>
<div data-for="south-west"></div>
etc
```

If the URL of the current page is http://www.mysite.com/shops/north-west.html, I want to find the div with the north-west data-attribute (div data-for="north-west)and assign an ID or class to it.

Can anyone help me out with this one? It needs to be speedy as the list of divs is quite long.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function() {  // probably should use a more narrow selector
    var str = $(this).data('for'); // accesses 'data-for' attribute
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(str))>=0) {
        // match found; do something
    }
});
```

Comment: An interesting solution, if not a bit fragile.  Beware data-for attributes of "foo" and "fooBar", as when you're looping through the divs with a URL that contains "fooBar", it'll hit/find on "foo" as well.

Comment: All very good answers, but this seems to be the best one for me. I would use an ID but that would mean invalidating my code as I'd have a lot of duplicate ID's.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about performance, ditch the custom data attribute (which is the slowest possible selector) and use the ID instead.

```
//Parse out the name of the HTML page you're on.
var selector = window.location.split('/')[2].replace('.html', '');
//Use it as your selector.
$('#' + selector).addClass('foo');
```

Otherwise use this selector:

```
$('div[data-for="' + selector + '"]').addClass('bar');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter method of jQuery

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/aSJ6Y/1)

```
loc = location.pathname;

$("div[data-for]").filter(function(index){
    var obj = loc.match(this.getAttribute("data-for"));
    if(obj)
        return obj.length > 0;
    else
        return false;
}).css({color:"red"})
```

#### EDIT: or better yet

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/aSJ6Y/3/)

```
$("div[data-for]").filter(function(index){
    var reg = new RegExp($(this).data("for"))
    return reg.test(location.pathname);
}).css({color:"red"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Metadata plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata) would do very well for this; e.g.

```
<div class="foo {bar: 'north-west'} baz"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
        var meta = $(this).metadata();
        console.log(meta);

        // And then do something with meta...
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your pathname and replace everything except for the name of the file for nothing, so you gonna have what you need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data_for = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]+).html/, '$1');
        $("div[data-for="+data_for+"]").something();
    });
</script>
```